# Wishlist Content

Tags: plugins, membership

I am using the Wishlist plugin for my membership site. My content is divided into 12 modules corresponding to 12 months. When a member upgrades from one level to the next,he has access to
current Level plus the previous Level(s) content, so for example if he is on Level 2 he has access to Level 2 plus Level 1 content;if on Level 3 he has access to Level 3 plus Level 2 plus Level 1 content and so on... The problem is that each membership level can see the content from the Level that they are currently on which is all okay with Level 1 but as a member moves on to the next Level, say Level 2, he can only "see" Level 2 content. What I want to do is to somehow show the Level 2 content when the member is logged in to that Level as well as the Level 1 content; I would like to do the same for all the other Levels. Also I would like to highlight the "old" content in some way from the current content. Is there any way out? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You will have a much better chance to get a satisfactory answer, if you'd narrow down your problem. Also: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to show your content for both levels you should need to mark the content protection level to be valid for those two levels.

For example a post the can be seen by level 1 and level 2 should be marked by those 2 levels.

Also you member the that need to the content should have access to those 2 levels.

Wishlist level are separate content and not build in specific order each level is on is own.